# Running a .bat file from Java having issues

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

```batch
@echo off
if "%1" == "" (
    echo "Usage: <outputDirectory>"
) else (

    if not exist "abc\cdf" mkdir abc\cdf

    if not exist "xyz" mkdir xyz
    if not exist "xyz\mno" mkdir xyz\mno
    xcopy export xyz\mno /e

    set xyz_JAR=xyz.jar
    set xyz_JAR_PATH=..\app\build\libs\

    set FILES=mno "%xyz_JAR%"

    copy "%xyz_JAR_PATH%%xyz_JAR%" xyz
    //copy ..\app\build\libs\xyz.jar xyz
    set ZIP_FILE=xyz_v0-8-0_export.zip

    if exist "xyz\mno\.zip" del xyz\mno\.zip
    cd "xyz"
    echo '%cd%'
    zip -r %ZIP_FILE% %FILES%
    del %xyz_JAR%
    echo y | del mno\config\*.*
    rmdir mno\config
    rmdir mno\out
    echo y | del /s mno\
    rmdir mno
    move %ZIP_FILE% ..\%1\%ZIP_FILE%
    cd ..
    rmdir xyz
)
```

Here is my .bat file which is being executed perfectly from command line. I would like to run the same from java where I am seeing issues at various stages

```java
        String command = "packageEGRC_export.bat"+" "+"exportEGRC";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe","/c",command},null,scriptDir);
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        int i = 0;
        while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)i);
        }
        process.waitFor();
        int exitValue = process.exitValue();
```

It is picking up bat file and executing till certain stage and failing at line

```
    copy "%xyz_JAR_PATH%%xyz_JAR%" xyz
```

Saying not able to find the file path. But if I replace that with, it's working fine

```
    copy ..\app\build\libs\xyz.jar xyz
```

And next not able to change directory to xyz --> `cd "xyz"`, it remains same working directory where it is being executed.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Note: I don't want to change anything on .bat file because it is working perfectly from command line.

Comment: What happens if you quote your relative path like you have those env variables quoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem is in .bat file itself: you set variable in **if** statement, but statement has to be read completely (compound expression) before execution. It is where variables are substituted. When you execute your script with Java, you have no environment variables set yet so expression

```
cd "%var%"
```

is populated with empty string hence Could not find error pops.

If you rewrite your code to set variables before entering if it will work.

Also you observe script work when called from command line because these variables were already set after first invocation of script. Simply check if your original script works after in freshly opened cmd.exe. Your script should fail.

Here is an example:

```
@echo off

if "%1" == "" (
    set xyz_JAR=xyz.jar
    set xyz_JAR_PATH=..\bat\

    echo "%xyz_JAR_PATH%%xyz_JAR%"
)
```

And invocation:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

D:\tmp\bat>test.bat
""

D:\tmp\bat>test.bat
"..\bat\xyz.jar"

D:\tmp\bat>
```

Comment: Also process has STDIN (process.getOutputStream()) and STDERR (process.getErrorStream()) which can block your script. So either close them right after process has started or read them out too.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use absolute paths 
2) dont cd, use pushd to change directory and popd to change back

Comment: tried pushd xyz and tried to print current working directory with echo '%cd%'  --> seems remains same working directory and not changed to xyz folder.